# Kaizala Storage conversations

Tags: kaizala, kaizala-action

Would you like to know if it is possible to store the conversations between Kaizala Groups and Participants, if it is possible to store the messages?

Answer (score 0):

Kaizala Pro subscription allows organizations to store/backup Org group conversations. Tenant Admin for Org can enable data retention for your Org groups using Kaizala Management Portal.

1. Sign-In to Kaizala Management Portal
2. Open Settings page
3. If you are Tenant Admin, you will find option to enable ‘Data retention for all org groups’